# Как определить путь загрузки библиотеки?

Tags: jni, java

Есть jni-библиотека, которая грузится так:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("library");
}
```

Как программно выяснить путь, по которому библиотека была реально загружена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Только посмотреть на library path и поискать её. Получить пути можно так:

```
System.getProperty("java.library.path")
```

Comment: Ну, ничего страшного. Поупражняетесь в работе с файлами :)

Answer (score 1):

А, я вас обманул :) На самом деле, можно ещё написать свой класслоадер.. там есть приватный метод findLibrar. Если у вас будет свой класслоадер, то вы сможете его вызвать и протащить... но это не очень хорошо выглядит...

Comment: и все равно он будет библиотеку сам искать. проще указать путь целиком :)